# Spree 3.1 CSS path for .spree-header background-image

Tags: css, spree

In Spree 3.1 Standard Themes (out of the box)

I tried to change background image.But not work. Perhaps the path is wrong. Help need.
Here what I did.

1. Upload image to be  `/app/assets/images/NewBackGroundImage.png`
2. Add css in `vendors/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/custom.css`

**CSS:**

```
.spree-header{
    background-image: url("/assets/images/NewBackGroundImage.png");
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

3. Here my inspect of the current page 
   [image]

This part is my attached screen shots for my comment of the answer below.

[image: Page Inspect]
[image: Files Tree]

At the inspect screen it clearly display error 404 (Not Found)
[image]

Tried change to use asset-url then 
[image]

**SCSS:**

Then Change my custom.css to custom.scss
[image: change custom to scss]

And this is the inspect shot  NOW IT WORK
[image: inspect shot]

Comment: since you have written the `css` styles so no need to keep in `vendor` dir

Comment: Hi illusionist. I tried put in /app/assets/images/stylesheets/custom.css but not work.(background and image)

Comment: the way you are referencing the image is wrong.. inn SCSS you have helper method like `asset-url(asset_name)` see this for help http://www.rubydoc.info/github/petebrowne/sprockets-sass/master/Sprockets/Sass/Functions#asset_url-instance_method

Comment: I tried put spree_header.jpg in the directory  and change the line to background: #444444  asset_url('spree_header.jpg'); still NO GOOD

Comment: try `asset-url` instead of `asset_url`

Comment: After try asset_url return invalid property value

Comment: I said `asset-url`

Comment: Yes, typo I tried both asset-url and asset_url (will attached screen shot above)

Comment: your file is `.css`, make it to `.scss`

Comment: IT'S WORK!!!. I try to read but missing the .scss stuffs. THX illusionist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, your page doesn't use your styles at all. Are you sure the div tag has the class "spree-header". Because in your browser it only has id "spree-header" and nothing about the respective class. Try to replace it from `.spree-header` to `#spree-header`. If there might be confrontation between styles, then you can always try the usage of `!important` tag: `url(...) !important;`

If the folder "vendors" is in the "app" folder, then you can use the relative path `url("../../../../../assets/images/NewBackGroundImage.png")` as well

Comment: Thanks Oleg. After I changed to #spree-header background color work but the image still no show. At Chrome=>inspect Styles (as attached if I botton off the background of my #spree-header then the original Spree 3.1 turn back to blue background it means the #spree-header is right but the url not work.

Comment: Finally it work: 1. Change .spree-header to #spree-header (in my case) 2. Change custom.css to custom.scss and 3. use asset-url for image path Big Thanks illusionist